# Form Invoke causes strange Exception

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, forms

I have the following method inside a Form

```
public void Bye()
{
     if (InvokeRequired && IsHandleCreated)
     {
         Invoke(new Action(Bye));
         return;
     }
     Close();
}
```

This form is created in the main form's thread, but this method is called from a `System.Threading.Timer` callback. The timer is created in the Main method, before calling Application.Run.

My application has many of these forms with the Bye method. The timer calls the Bye method of a random form each second.
If I keep the application running for a few minutes, I get an exception at the Invoke call.
The exception message is

```
Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.
```

The strange thing is that when the exception occurs, Visual Studio tells me that
both InvokeRequired and IsHandleCreated are false. How could it even try to call Invoke in this case?
What am I missing?

Comment: What is inside your Close() method?

Comment: @Tigran - It's clearly the Form.Close() method provided by the framework

Answer (score 1):

Change the order:

```
if (IsHandleCreated && InvokeRequired)
```

Regarding VS debugger: it may evaluate both properties to display their results in the Watch window, and at this point they may return false.

Comment: In this version InvokeRequired is called only if IsHandleCreated returns true.

Comment: Actually, this is still not safe, because this code runs in its own thread, and handle may be destroyed between IsHandleCreated  and InvokeRequired calls. Without additional information, I suggest you to catch appropriate exception on Invoke call (but don't catch Exception, only specific exception type).

Comment: @Tigran - It's called short circuiting.  In a boolean test situation using &&, if the first item is false, it will not evaluate the second condition.  Therefore, it will not call InvokeRequired if there is no window handle.

Comment: Doesn't actually solve the problem, IsHandleCreated might turn false a nanosecond after its value is tested.  Kaboom.  Or the Invoke request just disappears.  It is an unsolvable threading race.  Stop the thread before allowing the form to close.

Comment: @Hans Passant - agree, this is why I added new comment about exception. This code runs in the timer thread context, so this is not stopping a thread, it is necessary to stop the timer. But I have no idea whether last timer tick may arrive after stopping the timer.

Comment: user957455, maybe it is better to use Windows.Forms.Timer?

Comment: Makes it even harder, the timer could be stopped *while* the Elapsed event or callback is running.  And Elapsed is raised on a tp thread, it could be started *before* the timer is stopped but not start running until after.  Starting a timer is a lot easier than stopping it :)

Comment: Can someone quickly explain what the problem is, though. From the comments, I understood that between IsHandleCreated and InvokeRequired another thread might kill the form (or something else might cause IsHandleCreated to abruptly return false). Is this correct? I've tried checking for IsDisposed, but this returns false when the exception occurs. Also, the exception is at the Invoke call, not at InvokeRequired, and changing the order didn't have any effect.

Comment: You have Close call after this. It destroys the window. Post more code, we don't see how your timer works. What does this mean " The timer calls the Bye method of a random form each second"?

Comment: Form object can be destroyed as window, but exist as .NET class instance. Maybe timer calls its method after form is destroyed, but class instance still exists? Provide more information.